# CORS on react axios, but not on vanilla

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, axios, cors

I am trying to get data from a AWS endpoint using React/axios, but when I try to make a request I get this CORS error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://myAWS.com/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

when I try on my hosted github pages build, I also get the same error. But when I use Vanilla js on another hosted website it works, am I sendig my requests wrong on axios?

VANILLA

```
let body = {
    "name": "Bbbb 202",
    "email": "bbbb2220@bob.com",
    "password": "122",
    "wallet": "bbbbB202222"
  };
  
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = 'https://myAWS.com/login';
  http.open('POST', url, true);

  //Send the proper header information along with the request
  http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

  http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
      alert(http.responseText);
    }
  }
  http.send(body);
```

REACT

```
async SendRequest(method, url, callback, body){       
    axios.request({
        method: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(body),
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
        },
        url: url
    }) 
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        callback({
            status: response.status,
            data: response.data,
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        callback({
            status: err.status,
            data: err,
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: It is because you need to enable CORS in your headers. Add: ```'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',``` or  ```same-origin``` to your headers in you back end. ATTENTION: THIS OPENS A SECURITY HOLE IN YOUR SERVER SO PLEASE MAKE GOOD RESEARCH ABOUT IT BEFORE YOU USE IT.

Comment: But if it was a problem on the back-end the vanilla version would also not work right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are not the same request. The 'vanilla' request looks like it might qualify for what's known as a 'safe request'. To qualify as a safe request, content-type must be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (or 2 others), and not use any restricted HTTP methods.

I wrote more extensively about it here as well: https://evertpot.com/no-cors/

Comment: nice!! that was exactly what I needed to know thx